# Updating database when payment has gone thru

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, paypal-ipn

I can`t figure out how to update Premium in members.
When a user has paid and the payment has gone thru, i want to update Premium to YES

When the payment is done, nothing happends and when if my user has premium access it still says NO.

Any ideas here? Im using Paypal IPN

Here is my listener.php

```
<?php require('includes/config.php'); 



header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');

//
// STEP 2 - create the response we need to send back to PayPal for them to confirm that it's legit
//

$resp = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $parm => $var) 
    {
    $var = urlencode(stripslashes($var));
    $resp .= "&$parm=$var";
    }

// STEP 3 - Extract the data PayPal IPN has sent us, into local variables 

  $item_name        = $_POST['item_name'];
  $item_number      = $_POST['item_number'];
  $payment_status   = $_POST['payment_status'];
  $payment_amount   = $_POST['mc_gross'];
  $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
  $txn_id           = $_POST['txn_id'];
  $receiver_email   = $_POST['receiver_email'];
  $payer_email      = $_POST['payer_email'];
  $record_id        = $_POST['custom'];


// Right.. we've pre-pended "cmd=_notify-validate" to the same data that PayPal sent us (I've just shown some of the data PayPal gives us. A complete list
// is on their developer site.  Now we need to send it back to PayPal via HTTP.  To do that, we create a file with the right HTTP headers followed by 
// the data block we just createdand then send the whole bally lot back to PayPal using fsockopen


// STEP 4 - Get the HTTP header into a variable and send back the data we received so that PayPal can confirm it's genuine

$httphead = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$httphead .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$httphead .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($resp) . "\r\n\r\n";

 // Now create a ="file handle" for writing to a URL to paypal.com on Port 443 (the IPN port)

$errno ='';
$errstr='';

$fh = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// STEP 5 - Nearly done.  Now send the data back to PayPal so it can tell us if the IPN notification was genuine

 if (!$fh) {

// Uh oh. This means that we have not been able to get thru to the PayPal server.  It's an HTTP failure
//
// You need to handle this here according to your preferred business logic.  An email, a log message, a trip to the pub..
           } 

// Connection opened, so spit back the response and get PayPal's view whether it was an authentic notification         

else    {
           fputs ($fh, $httphead . $resp);
           while (!feof($fh))
                {
                $readresp = fgets ($fh, 1024);
                if (strcmp ($readresp, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
                    {





    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET Premium = 'YES' WHERE memberID = :memberID");
$stmt->execute(array(
        ':memberID' => $memberID

    ));


}







}

                else if (strcmp ($readresp, "INVALID") == 0) 
                    {

//              Man alive!  A hacking attempt?

                    }
                }
fclose ($fh);
        }
//
//
// STEP 6 - Pour yourself a cold one.
//
//

?>
```

I have struggles for a while now, and i still cant make it work. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Have you inserted any debugging code?  $test = $stmt->execute($foo);

if (!$test) echo "Statement didn't execute! " . $db->error;

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey No, but that wouldt work in listener.php ? Because i get re-directed before 10 seconds

Comment: Add die(); ... ?

Comment: ... what the f do you think happens if $var contains a slash? or an `&` ? or an `=` ? that's a completely wrong way to encode variables to anything whatsoever, you're risking significant data corruption. learn to do it properly, eg urlencode() or http_build_query

Answer (score 0):

Remember PayPal IPN is not work on local Machine You can validate it using PayPal simulator and You have to send it via "notify_url" or setup IPN handler url into your paypal account Here is the sample code i hope it helps you.

```
    $url_parsed = parse_url($paypal_url);
    $post_string = '';
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $field => $value) {
        $post_string .= $field . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
    }
    $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command
    // get the correct paypal url to post request to
    $paypal_mode_status = $ipn_data; //get_option('im_sabdbox_mode');
    if ($paypal_mode_status == true)
    $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
    else
    $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
    $ipn_response = '';

    if (!$fp) {
    // could not open the connection. If loggin is on, the error message
    // will be in the log.
        $ipn_status = "fsockopen error no. $err_num: $err_str";
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
        echo 'fsockopen fail';
        }
        return false;
    } else {
    // Post the data back to paypal
        fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");

        // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
        while (!feof($fp)) {
        $ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp); // close connection
    }
    // Invalid IPN transaction. Check the $ipn_status and log for details.
    if (!preg_match("/VERIFIED/s", $ipn_response)) {
        $ipn_status = 'IPN Validation Failed';

        if ($ipn_data == true) {
        echo 'Validation fail';
        print_r($_REQUEST);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        $ipn_status = "IPN VERIFIED";
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
        echo 'SUCCESS';
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Should i use this instead in in listener.php?

Comment: Yes you can use this into your listener.php(Your IPN) file